# Sphinx hyperlink: non-whitespace before opening backtick

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, docutils

My hyperlinks aren't detected if there is a '/' char or a letter (eg 'V') immediately before the opening backtick.

Is there a workaround for this which doesn't introduce whitespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape a space character between the non-whitespace character and the opening backtick, like so:

```
v\ `Python <https://www.python.org>`_
```

Will render as:

```
<p>v<a class="reference external" href="https://www.python.org">Python</a></p>
```