# Color text in reStructuredText - files (.rst) without leading space character in front of :color:`text`

Tags: html, css, colors, restructuredtext

The text/code piece is the following:

```
Timestamps
-----------

...

1) UTC+2: 2021-06-10T09:00:42:red:`+02:00`
2) UTC: 2021-06-10T09:00:42:red:`Z`
```

Undesired result (**no colored text** achieved):
[image]

It works when inserting a space in front of `:red:`, but this is not an acceptable workaround as the [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)-format does not allow for spaces.

Undesired result of workaround (**colored text achieved, but with spaces**):
[image: colored text with spaces]

*How can I achieve colored text without undesired spaces in front of the colored piece?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you realized, you must have a space before your role.  Next you can escape the space with a backslash (`\`).

```
.. raw:: html

    <style> .red {color:red} </style>

.. role:: red

1) UTC+2: 2021-06-10T09:00:42\ :red:`+02:00`
2) UTC: 2021-06-10T09:00:42\ :red:`Z`
```

See a similar question and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57704047/2214933).