# Character right after closing backtick in rst

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am writing some sphinx documentation.  Suppose classes `Foo` and `Bar` are in the documentation.  Elsewhere I would like to say

```
A :class:`~.Foo` contains multiple :class:`~.Bar`s.
```

and get [Foo] to be linked and a link that looks like [Bar]s,

```
A [Foo] contains multiple [Bar]s.
```

but get a warning

```
WARNING: Inline interpreted text or phrase reference start-string without end-string.
```

and a failure to render / link.  The rendered page looks like

```
A [Foo] contains multiple :class:`~.Bar`s.
```

instead.

**How may I achieve an automatic link to a class + a suffix (like -s, -ly, -ing) but no space in between in rst/restructured text/sphinx?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reStructuredText you can escape a space before and after roles and backticks, then place other characters next to the role.

Try this:

```
A :class:`~.Foo` contains multiple :class:`~.Bar`\ s.
```

See a similar question and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57704047/2214933).

Another option is to use [MyST](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/) which allows more flexible formatting without such obscure syntax.

Comment: Worked straight away!